# can't get updated information with cache in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I used cached action in play framework 2.2.6. However, it always displays the same information even when i edited the data or add a new record in database.I had to clear the browser data in order to show the updated data.Is there a way to get the updated data immediately with cached action?

```
def notification() = Cached("notification") {
   Action {
     implicit request =>
     Ok(views.html.notiifcationlist())
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition of any cache you have to flush it on update. Alternatively you can set TTL while putting something to the cache.